# I can't load the sp package in R

Tags: r

I want to use RGDAL and Raster and the sp package is a dependency of Raster. When I try to load the sp Package I get an error message and the Raster package can't load

I have uninstalled the package, re-downloaded and re-installed and nothing changed. Updating R to 3.6.0 had no effect either.

Error Message reads:

> "Error: package or namespace load failed "sp" in rbind(info, getNameSpace(env, "s3methods")) number of columns of matrices must match (see arg 2)

Comment: Isn't it `getNamespace()` instead of `getNameSpace()` ? And also check out that environment objects can be bound via `rbind()`: maybe a list would be better.

Comment: how do you install? On what OS? Can you show the session from start to error with all messages? `install.packages("sp"); library(sp)`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. In order to help you slightly better, try to provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) or at least a code section, with the code that you run to get your current error. Other informations like session info, that can be obtained using `session_info()` from the `devtools` package is likely to help as well. This will make it easier to locate why the error is happening, as the error message alone (in this case) is rather unhelpful.